# A concave function as supremum of upper semi continuous is upper semi continuous

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

We define a affine(concave), upper semi continuous function and bounded function $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$, where $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{k}$ is compact and convex set. Assume that $T$ is an affine and upper semi continuous function on $X$. Let $S$ be a concave function on a compact and convex set $A$ defined by $S(t)=\sup\{f(x), T(x)=t\}$.

$\textbf{Question}$: Is $S$ upper semi-continuous?

My attempt: Since $S$ is concave, $S$ is continuous in the interior of $X$. On the other hand, the supremum of upper semicontinuous function is not necessarily upper semi-continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Your assumptions imply $f$ is continuous and $X$ is compact by assumption. It should not be too hard to prove $S$ is usc using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of usc.

Here is a more geometric argument:

One generally answers these questions by going through epigraphs. Function is lsc ($-f$ here) if the epigraph $\mathrm{epi}(-f) = \{(x,y)|y\geq -f(x)\}$ is closed.

So, you need to show that the epigraph of $-S$ is closed. But,
$$
   \mathrm{epi}(-S) = \{(t,y)|y\geq -S(t)\} = \{(t,y)|y\geq -f(x),\ Tx=t\}
$$
i.e. $\mathrm{epi}(-S)$ is the projection of the set $\mathrm{epi}(-f)$, $Tx=t$. So, by compactness of $X$ and continuity of $f$, also $S$ is usc.

Comment: Why $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Could you a bit explain about the projection?

Comment: Is it true that even $f$ was ups not continuous, then the last line works?

Comment: You need usc of $f$ for this argument to work.

Comment: The projection thing is this:

Comment: Thanks. I guessed I just need ups of $f$.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could explain to me the projection thing

Comment: Define the linear map $\Pi(x,y) = (Tx,y)$. Then $\Pi\{(x,y)|y\geq -f(x)\} = \{(Tx,y)|y\geq-f(x)\} = \{(t,y)|y\geq -f(x), Tx=t\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: The (lower semi-) continuity thing is a bit messy to show, but the idea is to use concavity and the fact that $X$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: Oh! great, thanks. I will work on it.

Comment: You, don't need continuity of $f$ for $S$ to be usc. The geometric picture shows you where things could go wrong (say, if $X$ were not compact).